# testing angular controller (method / service calls) using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test a small controller written in AngularJS using Jasmin.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('bsp.account')
    .controller('Account', Account);

/* @ngInject */
function Account(userService, accountService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.title = 'Account';

    vm.username = userService.getUsername();
    vm.showPasswordModal = accountService.showPasswordModal;
    vm.showLogoutModal = accountService.showLogoutModal;
}
})();
```

I want to test vm.username ,vm.showPersonModal and vm.showLogoutModal.these are all the reference to the service injected in the controller.
I am fairly new and slowly trying to build my concept in testing.
Below is the piece of test cases running now,

```
describe('Account', function() {
  var scope, controller, userServiceMock,accountServiceMock;
  beforeEach(module('bsp'));
  beforeEach(function() {
    userServiceMock = {
      getUsername: function(){} 
    };
    accountServiceMock = {
      showPasswordModal :function(){}
    };
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('Account', {
      'userService': userServiceMock,
      'accountService':accountServiceMock
    });
  }));

 describe('testing Title',function(){
  it('checkTitle', function(){
    expect(controller.title).toEqual('Account'); 
  });  
 });


});
```

Thank You for all your suggestions

Comment: Looks like you're off to a good start. What's the problem?

Comment: @Phil i have no clue how to test those three lines of code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only problems I can see is that

1. You're bootstrapping the wrong module (should be `'bsp.account'` instead of `'bsp'`)
2. You've not provided a means to test that your service methods are called

You can address the latter using [spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Spies). For example

```
describe('Account', function() {
    var controller, userServiceMock, accountServiceMock;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('bsp.account');

        userServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('userService', ['getUsername']);
        userServiceMock.getUsername.and.returnValue('testUser');

        accountServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('accountService', ['showPasswordModal', 'showLogoutModal']);

        inject(function($controller) {
            controller = $controller('Account', {
                userService: userServiceMock,
                accountService: accountServiceMock
            });
        });
    });

    it('assigns values from services', function() {
        expect(userServiceMock.getUsername).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(controller.username).toEqual('testUser');
        expect(controller.showPasswordModal).toBe(accountServiceMock.showPasswordModal);
        expect(controller.showLogoutModal).toBe(accountServiceMock.showLogoutModal);
    });
});
```

Comment: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'userServiceMock.getUsername.and.returnValue')at /vagrant/frontend/src/app/account/account.controller.spec.js:47
 Expected spy userService.getUsername to have been called.
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'controller.username')
     at /vagrant/frontend/src/app/account/account.controller.spec.js:62

Comment: ,m getting this error in the test,  the method getusername is ----self.getUsername = function() {
        return getUserObj().username;
      };

Comment: @sg28 what version of Jasmine? If 1.x the method is [`andReturn`](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>andReturn</code>) instead of `and.returnValue`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion (had to change to andReturn) ,the solution worked.Just one more question ,i really have to pick up a lot about jasmin testing,any suggestions where to look for apart for the jasmine.github.io/ site or the https://angularjs.org(these needs a more update ).Thank you very much,again